# Why Is My JavaScript Object Throwing An Undefined Error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am getting this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kbsrc' of undefined
```

I get this error because I think there may be something wrong with the way I created my JavaScript Object.  I have never created an object that is as multidimensional as this one so I am probably screwing up the syntax somewhere.  I generate the objects in the mark-up file here:

```
var kb_work = {}
    kb_work['2014'] = {};
        kb_work['2014']['kbid'] = ["51","47"];
        kb_work['2014']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/images-4.jpeg","images\/imgres-3.jpeg"];
        kb_work['2014']['kbtitle'] = ["shalom","Test 6"];
        kb_work['2014']['kbmedium'] = ["2x2","Oil"];
        kb_work['2014']['kbsize'] = ["2x2","2x6"];
        kb_work['2014']['kbdate'] = ["2014","2014"];
    kb_work['2013'] = {};
        kb_work['2013']['kbid'] = ["55","54","53","52","50"];
        kb_work['2013']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/imgres-4.jpeg","images\/imgres-3.jpeg","images\/imgres-1.jpeg","images\/images.jpeg","images\/images-3.jpeg"];
        kb_work['2013']['kbtitle'] = ["totally","heheh","Howdy","tickle","hi"];
        kb_work['2013']['kbmedium'] = ["oil","oil","2x2","o","oil"];
        kb_work['2013']['kbsize'] = ["2x2","2x2","2x2","2x2","2x1"];
        kb_work['2013']['kbdate'] = ["2013","2013","2013","2013","2013"];
    kb_work['2012'] = {};
        kb_work['2012']['kbid'] = ["49"];
        kb_work['2012']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/images-2.jpeg"];
        kb_work['2012']['kbtitle'] = ["chicked"];
        kb_work['2012']['kbmedium'] = ["oil"];
        kb_work['2012']['kbsize'] = ["3x4"];
        kb_work['2012']['kbdate'] = ["2012"];
```

Each of these arrays have only one value right now, but will grow as the user adds work.  Following this I link to a file, which contains this function (I commented on the specific line) that the TypeError refers to:

```
function changeGal(gallery_year) {
  $("#gallery-control-bar").fadeOut(t);
  $("#gallery-image").fadeOut(t);
  $("#info").fadeOut(t);
  $("#gallery-viewer").fadeOut(t);

  //this is where the script chokes up referring to "currentImg" which is 0 and refers to the first value in the array "['2014']['kbsrc']".

    $("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + kb_work[gallery_year]['kbsrc'][currentImg] + "'>");
    $("#gallery-title").html(kb_work[gallery_year]['kbtitle'][currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-medium").html(kb_work[gallery_year]['kbmedium'][currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-size").html(kb_work[gallery_year]['kbsize'][currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-date").html(kb_work[gallery_year]['kbdate'][currentImg]);

  $("#gallery-control-bar").delay(t + d).fadeIn(t);
  $("#gallery-image").delay(t + d).fadeIn(t);
  $("#info").delay(t + d).fadeIn(t);

  var userCurrent = currentImg + 1;
  var userTotal = kb_work[gallery_year][0].length;

  $("#current-post").html(userCurrent);
  $("#post-total").html(userTotal);

  var galWidth = $("#gallery-image" > "img").width();
  $("#gallery").width(galWidth);

}
```

Any thoughts to why it cannot reference the value?

Comment: This is a very odd way to build an object, why create an array but never use it as an array?  It should probably look more like this  `kbwork={'2014':{kbid:46,kbsrc:'somethimg.png', ...}, '2013':{...}, ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
$("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + kb_work[gallery_year][gallery_year + '.kbsrc'][currentImg] + "'>");
```

because it looks like `gallery_year` is a year value like 2013, but the key is a concatenation string value like `2013.kbsrc`

There is another problem with your structure because `kb_work[year]` should be an obeject not an array, again the second level of keys need not have the year again.

So the structure can be updated to

```
var kb_work = {}
kb_work['2014'] = {};
kb_work['2014']['kbid'] = ["46"];
kb_work['2014']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/screen shot 2014-03-05 at 11.31.04 pm.png"];
kb_work['2014']['kbtitle'] = ["Test 5"];
kb_work['2014']['kbmedium'] = ["Oil"];
kb_work['2014']['kbsize'] = ["2x5"];
kb_work['2014']['kbdate'] = ["2014"];
kb_work['2013'] = {};
kb_work['2013']['kbid'] = ["44"];
kb_work['2013']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/screen shot 2014-03-05 at 11.31.04 pm.png"];
kb_work['2013']['kbtitle'] = ["Test 3"];
kb_work['2013']['kbmedium'] = ["Oil"];
kb_work['2013']['kbsize'] = ["2x1"];
kb_work['2013']['kbdate'] = ["2013"];
kb_work['2012'] = {};
kb_work['2012']['kbid'] = ["45"];
kb_work['2012']['kbsrc'] = ["images\/screen shot 2014-03-05 at 11.31.04 pm.png"];
kb_work['2012']['kbtitle'] = ["Test 4"];
kb_work['2012']['kbmedium'] = ["Oil"];
kb_work['2012']['kbsize'] = ["2x3"];
kb_work['2012']['kbdate'] = ["2012"];
```

then to access it

```
kb_work[gallery_year]['kbsrc'][currentImg]
```

Comment: This gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kbsrc' of undefined ` still pointing to the same line which is the function in the javascript file

Comment: what is the value of `gallery_year`?

Comment: Wow, realized `gallery_year` was a wrong value!  This solves it!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting shows that you think this works differently to how it actually works...

```
var kb_work = {}
    kb_work['2014'] = new Array();
        kb_work['2014.kbid'] = ["46"];
```

Actually results in an object like this: `{"2014":[],"2014.kbid":["46"]}`

I believe you want this:

```
var kb_work = {
    '2014': [
        { 'kbid': ["46"] }
     ]
};
```

Which results in an object like this: `{"2014":[{"kbid":["46"]}]}`

Now you can access:

```
kb_work['2014'][0].kbid[0] // 46
```

And you can pass in the year as a variable containing the string and the `0`s can be a variable containing the index.

You can add multiple lines like this:

```
var kb_work = {
    '2014': [
        { 'kbid': ["46"] },
        { 'kbid': ["62"] },
        { 'kbid': ["90"] }
     ]
};
```

Comment: so would I add multiple lines for each of the components of a year e.g. `'2014': [{ 'kbid': ["46"] }],'2014': [{ 'kbsrc': ["images/src.jpg"] }]` and then if I wanted to access the `kbsrc` I would write `kb_work['2014'][1].kbsrc[0]`?

Comment: I've added an example of multiple lines.